# Can't get Memcache to work

Tags: apache, memcached, xampp

I've just installed Memcache in XAMPP on OS X Mountain Lion and I'm trying to run it using:

```
 $memcache = new Memcache();
$memcache>connect('127.0.0.1', 11211) or die ("Could not connect");
```

This returns:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Memcache' not found in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/mysite/myfile.php on line 123
```

What can I do to fix this?

I installed Memcache using [this guide](http://wiki.cerbweb.com/Setup%3aDevelopment/XAMPP/Mac_OS_X)

In my php.ini file I have `extension="memcache.so"`

In phpinfo.php I have `mod_mem_cache`

Answer (score 1):

First off, check that your syntax is correct.
You are missing a pointer in the example code that you've submitted. "->".
Also, I am unable to check if the connection is successful or not by using "or die",
therefor I usually check the connection object itself.

```
$memcache = new Memcache();
$memcache->connect('127.0.0.1', 11211);

if ($memcache === FALSE){
    echo 'Unable to connect to memcache';
}
```

If this does not work, then check that you really do have memcache available.
Open up a terminal on your OSX and run:

```
php --info | grep '^memcache'
```

Comment: I tried your code and it is still the same error. The error is pointing to the line that says: `$memcache = new Memcache();` I also tried to run  `php --info | grep '^memcache'` but that doesn't return anything. Nothing at all.

Comment: Then I'm quite sure that you do not have the memcache (or memcached) library installed. Look over the installation manual for XAMPP that you've mentioned above.

Have you restarted your Apache-instance to load the changes that you've made? (Also mentioned in the guide)

Comment: I searched the XAMPP folder for memcache and found a folder with two files: `example.php` and `memcache.php`. I moved the `memcache.php` file to my project directory and imported it and ran the the code that you suggested. Now a popup appears which want my username and password for Memcache Login. I haven't set any username or password, what are the default values?